# Use readHTMLTable over a List of Dates and Create New Date Column with Data

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping, rcurl

I am attempting to write a loop to perform `readHTMLTable()` over a list of sequential dates that I provide via a formula. I have successfully imported all the data between the dates. However, that data does not feature a date column, so using the sequence of dates I provide the loop, I would like the loop to readHTMLTable and then add a new column with the date it used for that iteration.

Here is what I have so far:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(plyr)

# create the days
x <- seq(as.Date("2015-04-10"), as.Date("2015-04-15"), by = "day")

# create a url template for sprintf()
utmp <- "http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=%d&day=%d&year=%d"

# convert to numeric matrix after splitting for year, month, day
m <- do.call(rbind, lapply(strsplit(as.character(x), "-"), type.convert))

# create the list to hold the results
tables <- vector("list", length(m))

# get the tables
for(i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
  # create the url for the day and if it exists, read it - if not, NULL
  tables[[i]] <- if(url.exists(u <- sprintf(utmp, m[i, 2], m[i, 3], m[i, 1]))) 
    readHTMLTable(u, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  else NULL
}

data <- ldply(tables,data.frame)
```

So basically, I would like my final data frame to feature `m` as a new column called something like `data$Date`.

Thanks for any and all help and let me know if you need any clarification!

Comment: Without a `Sys.sleep` in the loop you are in violation of the site's [terms of service](http://www.sports-reference.com/termsofuse.shtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `mapply()` (the multivariate function of the apply family) where you pass the list of dates, urls, and table iterator to download html tables. You can avoid the matrix handling as `format()` can extract parts of date types. Also, consider not using the NULL for non-existent urls as it may not bind afterward. Simply filter out empty elements.

```
# LIST OF DATES
x <- lapply(0:5, function(i) as.Date("2015-04-10")+i)     

# LIST OF URLS
utmp <- "http://www.basketball-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=%d&day=%d&year=%d"
urlist <- c(lapply(x, function(i) sprintf(utmp, as.numeric(format(i, '%m')), 
                                                as.numeric(format(i, '%d')), 
                                                as.numeric(format(i, '%y')))))

# USER DEFINED FUNCTION
tables <- vector("list", length(x))
tabledwnld <- function(dt, url, i) {                      
                   if (url.exists(url)) {
                      tableNodes <- readHTMLTable(url)                       
                      tables[[i]] <- tableNodes[[1]]
                      tables[[i]]['Date'] <- dt
                      return(tables)
                   } 
              }
# APPLY ABOVE FUNCTION (RETURNS LARGE MATRIX OF TABLES)
data <- mapply(tabledwnld, x, urlist, 1:6)

# BIND TO DATA FRAME
finaldata <- do.call(rbind, data)
```

Also, pay heed to @hrbrmstr's warning in the comments, as site reads below. You may want to space out your table download:

> Except as specifically provided in this paragraph, you agree not to
>   use or launch any automated system, including without limitation,
>   robots, spiders, offline readers, or like devices, that accesses the
>   Site in a manner which sends more request messages to the Site server
>   in any given period of time than a typical human would normally
>   produce in the same period by using a conventional on-line Web browser
>   to read, view, and submit materials.

Comment: Hey thanks for being willing to help out. Unfortunately, on my end your code is not reproducible. I receive an error about an unexpected symbol in the `tabledwnld` function, another error about not being able to find an inherited method for `readHTMLTable`, an error about the `dt` part of the loop regarding invalid type/length (closure/0) in vector allocation, and then finally a couple errors about unexpected "}". Any idea why I would see these on my end?

Comment: See update. The `if` statement was not properly wrapped in parentheses. Additionally, XML library's [readHTMLTable](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/xml/docs/readhtmltable) does not directly create a dataframe but retrieves the URL's parsed `<table>` node set.

Comment: Thanks! The code all runs now. However, I'm still having an issue where the `tables` command returns a List of 0, which then makes the `data` command return 0 obs. of 0 variables.

Comment: Check source code of web page, see if the table you want is the first `<table>`. If not and is second, third, fourth, etc. change number in brackets `tableNodes[[NewNumber]]`

Comment: Okay thanks. Can I just ask you if your code, as it is currently written, works as you would like it to or do you also get empty results?

Comment: My apologies. I guess we're both learning! I did not actually run for fear of the site's policy. I should have added a return on `mapply()` and pass function result to data. See update which has been tested, `finaldata` should yield 1,222 obs and 27 vars. with `Date` as the last column.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help. I understand not wanting to violate ToS and I'm trying to not overload the site through my scraping so I'll look into adding a Sys.sleep command as @hrbrmstr suggested.